# Slow down snake speed in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

So I'm making a simple snake game in c++ terminal but I want to be able to slow the snake down without using the legacy console setting.

Here is my code,

```
using namespace std;



Snake snake({ WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 }, 1);
Food food;

int score;

void ShowConsoleCursor(bool showFlag)
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = showFlag;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
}

void board() {
    COORD snake_pos = snake.get_pos();
    COORD food_pos = food.get_pos();

    vector<COORD> snake_body = snake.get_body();

    cout << "SCORE: " << score << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        cout << "\t\t#";
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH - 2; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == HEIGHT - 1) cout << '#';
                else if (i == snake_pos.Y && j + 1 == snake_pos.X) cout << 'O';
                else if (i == food_pos.Y && j + 1 == food_pos.X) cout << '*';
                else {
                    bool isBodyPart = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k < snake_body.size() - 1; k++) {
                        if (i == snake_body[k].Y && j + 1 == snake_body[k].X) {
                            cout << 'o';
                            isBodyPart = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    if (!isBodyPart) cout << ' ';
                }
        }
            cout << "#\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    score = 0;
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);
    srand(time(NULL));
    food.gen_food();
    char game_over = false;
    while (!game_over) {
        board();
        if (_kbhit()) {
            switch (_getch()) {
            case 'w': snake.change_dir('u'); break;
            case 's': snake.change_dir('d'); break;
            case 'a': snake.change_dir('l'); break;
            case 'd': snake.change_dir('r'); break;
            }
        }
        if (snake.collided()) game_over = true;

        if (snake.eaten(food.get_pos())) {
            food.gen_food();
            snake.grow();
            score++;
        }
        
        snake.move_snake();
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), { 0, 0 });
    }

    board();

    
}
```

I'm using SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), { 0, 0 }); to update the position of the cursor and cout << "#\n"; to reset the position. This way it updates without looking choppy.

I tried to use a clock and input some kind of delay but I don't think it works well with the function.

Comment: Why don't you think a clock with some sort of delay works? What other solution apart from "some kind of delay" do you think you'll get ?

Comment: A timer is exactly the kind of simple solution you need. Put it in your game loop, but to do this you will need to process _all_ pending keys on each update (not just the next key). To reduce the "choppy" behavior, the Windows console supports double-buffering.

Comment: Take a look: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html